# My application show the wrong name

Tags: java, macos

I wrote a java application called "screen" and made that into an app on mac. The app works fine, but when I open the app, and click on the name on the toolbar, it does not refer to it as "screen". [image: It says the name is "Main"].

Is there a way that I can change from "About Main", "Hide Main" and "Quit Main" to "About screen", "Hide Screen" and "Quit Screen"?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319471/how-to-change-the-java-application-name-shown-in-the-mac-os-x-launchpad) yet?

Comment: It's funny, we have complete different problems. I have the name showing on the menu bar, but no on the menu items. But they have the menu items correct, but not the name.

Comment: What kind of framework did you use? JavaFX? Swing? Pure console?

Comment: I used eclipse if that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

"-Xdock:name=appName"
Add this to the cfg file in the resources folder.